# Working with jQuery animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a magnification plugin which works in the following way:

1) The highlighted portion of the page is displayed in a separate box(an html element) which shows its enlarged version.

2) There are several ways to play with this box's configuration like moving it up,down,left,right using the .animate function such as:

On pressing the Up arrow on the keyboard

```
$('#monitor').animate({'marginTop': '+=50px'}, 'fast' ); return false; break;
```

The problem now comes when the user would want the #monitor's size to be customised.
One possible way of doing it would be suggesting some alphabet for increasing box size as well as one for decreasing size
What solution is possible for this problem?

Please refer the above code segment of jQuery

Comment: Are you asking which keys you should assign to changing the size of the box, or how to change the size of the box?

Comment: You can use the `.animate()` function to change the height and/or width depending on the button pressed, very similarly to the code snippet you provided. You may need to adjust the position, too, to keep the box from going off the screen

Comment: thank you
can you please provide a code snippet similar to above where I can alter both the width and height of the box simultaneously

Comment: The [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has some good examples.

Comment: I tried the API Docs and it worked
Now the problem arises that when I reduce the size of the box on the press of lets say alphabet "L" the height has to reduce to 50% which it does but the text material is brimming out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your last comment " box on the press of lets say alphabet "L" the height has to reduce to 50% which it does but the text material is brimming out of the box"

you have animate font size also at the same time with regard to the box you animate

```
$( "#go1" ).click(function(){
  $( "#block1" ).animate( { width: "90%" }, { queue: false, duration: 3000 })
     .animate({ fontSize: "24px" }, 1500 )
     .animate({ borderRightWidth: "15px" }, 1500 );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: oh.. if it really help you you can upvote and accept this as answer

Comment: when I enlarge the box by pressing "L" the box is enlarged and so is the text but cannot limit the text to stay within the box. It now also sometimes overflows the box
Also when I press S(after L) the gap between the Box and  text 
widens. S is for reducing the box size
Help!!!!!

Comment: you are the one who setting the box size and font size.  give proper width and size  ,if not staying in box reduce font . did you try the examples

Comment: I tried what you said(zod) But somehow i wanted the reduction and expansion of the box to be in sync with the text